# How to change the default style of a XAML control?

Tags: xaml, styles, pivot, uwp

I want to change the default style or theme of the pivot control and I've found some really cool samples online, but i don't know where to place them in.
should i make a new file or edit an existing  one?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new XAML ResourceDictionary in the project, where you can place these styles.

After that you have to include this resource dictionary as merged dictionary in the App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///MyFolder/MyResourceDictionary.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Of course you don't have to create seperate file for these resources, you can place these to any Resources collection. Like to the `Application.Resources` in App.xaml or to the `Page.Resources`in the page's xaml.

A style will be default to the target control, if you don't provide any `x:Key=""` to them in the resource collection. These are implicit styles.